# Is it possible to generate internal reset pulse in verilog with machxo3lf fpga?

Tags: verilog, reset, lattice

I have a board without Reset input for my design. But I need to reset at fpga startup.
Is there a verilog solution to generate this pulse ?

Comment: What does the FPGA's data sheet say about resets?  That's the first place you should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution thanks to [lvd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/405372/68518) and [tom-carpenter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/228839/68518). Many FPGA can initialize there registers to 0 and nothing else. It's the case of machxo3.

Then doing that works for me:

```
reg [3:0] rst_cnt = 0;
wire rst_n = rst_cnt[3];

always @(posedge clk)
if( !rst_n )
    rst_cnt <= rst_cnt + 1;
```

Initial statement is ignored by lattice synthesis toolchain (even with synplify) if it's not a «force» or a memory initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet on MachXO says that

> The MachXO registers in PFU and sysI/O can be configured to be SET or
>   RESET. After power up and deviceconfigured, the device enters into
>   user mode with these registers SET/RESET according to the
>   configuration set- ting, allowing device entering to a known state for
>   predictable system function.

Therefore, the simplest thing you can do is to configure all `regs` that need to be initialized with `initial` verilog construct or the equivalent understood by the tools.

If you still need a 'traditional' reset pulse, you can do it like this:

```
reg [3:0] rst_cnt;

wire rst_n = rst_cnt[3];

initial rst_cnt=4'd0;

always @(posedge clk)
if( !rst_n )
    rst_cnt <= rst_cnt + 4'd1;
```

This code again relies on the ability to set initial (power-on) values for the flipflops of MachXO.

Comment: In fact, that does not work in fact : "WARNING - CG532 :[...] |Within an initial block, only Verilog force statements and memory $readmemh/$readmemb initialization statements are recognized, and all other content is ignored."